# Android: how to decrypt an openssl encrypted file with RSA key?

Tags: android, encryption, openssl

I need to transfer a file from server to android. The file is encrypted by openssl with RSA private key, and android should decrypt it with the corresponding public key. How should i implement it in android? Could someone give me an example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've added some example code on how to do this on Android in my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12101100/546054