# Decrypt a file in Android with private key (OpenSSl)

Tags: java, android, encryption, openssl

I generated two keys (public and private) with Ubuntu.
Now I encrypted a **file** with Ubuntu 14 using Public Key and **OpenSSL** and I want to decrypt it in Android with they Private Key that i generated previously.

How can I do that?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037780/convert-php-rsa-publickey-into-android-publickey/12101100#12101100

Comment: Remove non useful phrases "help ..." and rephrase the question.